# Bot stopped working even though code is fine

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.9

This is my first time coding a discord bot and I have been following tutorials mainly but I wanted to make a unique game so I tried to make it myself. But after messing around with it for a while I realized that the only part of my code that works is the mcguccy is an idiot part none of the client. Command parts work.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@client.command()
async def ping1(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong!")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("cranking 90s on shitters"))
    print("bot is ready!")


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} has joined :weary:.')


@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member} has left :weary:')


@client.command()
async def helb(ctx):
    await ctx.send('@everyone look at this idiot')


@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'here you go: {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')


@client.command()
async def commands(ctx):
    await ctx.send('1. helb it will help you. 2. ping it will tell you the bots ping. ')


@client.command()
async def overlord(ctx):
    await ctx.send("muah hah hah YOUR SERVER IS MINE")

keywords = ["mcguccy is an idiot", "kick mcguccy", "i want to nuke the server"]


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for i in range(len(keywords)):
        if keywords[i] in message.content:
            for j in range(20):
                await message.channel.send(f"@everyone someone has spammed :weary:")
```

Comment: Hey mcguccy, welcome to stack! Just to be clear, were your commands working before? Is your `on_message` event still working? Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to look at here:

##### Your `client` variable is a `Bot` type, not a `Client` type.

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
```

This means you need to use `@bot` decorators instead of `@client` decorators:

```py
@client.command()
async def helb(ctx):
    ...
# Becomes
@bot.command()
async def helb(ctx):
    ...
```

##### The `.run()` method is never called.

Because of this, the bot's event loop doesn't start.  You need to initialize the [Client event loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.run) so the bot can listen for commands to pass:

```py
if __name__=='__main__':
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

That code needs to be the very last statement run in the file, as it's blocking.

##### The `.run()` command requires an API token.

You can acquire said token by [creating a bot account](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/discord.html#discord-intro) if you don't have one already.  If you do have one, you'll need to pass it as the first paramater to the `.run()` method.

Comment: Hey there PTH, I may be wrong, but I believe that your first point doesn't really change anything, or may be incorrect. Since Mcguccy originally defined their `commands.Bot` as `client`, there would be no need to change all of their commands to `bot`. If this was the case, you could need to have defined `commands.Bot` as bot, such as with `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')`, otherwise there would be no changes necessary on that part. Please do correct me if I am wrong, happy coding!